# Pandas Dataframe Time column has float values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-cleaning

I am doing a cleaning of my Database. In one of the tables, the time column has values like 0.013391204. I am unable to convert this to time [mm:ss] format. Is there a function to convert this to the required format [mm:ss]
The head for the column

```
0           20:00
1    0.013391204
2    0.013333333
3    0.012708333
4    0.012280093
```

Use the below reproducible data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"time": ["20:00", "0.013391204", "0.013333333", "0.012708333", "0.012280093"]})
```

I expect the output to be like the first row of the column values shown above.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: in which format other values are in seconds/minutes/hour??

Comment: Other values, like in the first row, are in the mm:ss format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the correct time interpretation for say the first entry? `0.013391204` is it `48 seconds`?

Because, if we use `datetime` module we can convert float into the time format:

Updating answer to add the new information

```
import datetime
datetime.timedelta(days = 0.013391204)
str(datetime.timedelta(days = 0.013391204))

Output:'0:19:17.000026'
```

Hope this helps :))

Comment: Hi Joe. According to the data, this value must be somewhere around 19 mins and x secs.

Comment: May I know how did these float values came into existence? What is the logic/relation between `19 mins` and `0.013391204`?

Comment: Joe. It is known that the event happened at around 19 mins. When I received this data, the time column showed the float value.

Comment: I see, that was the difference. Use the same code man, and change the parameters into `days`, instead of `hours` and you would obtain the value you need, editing the answer now :)). Btw, don't forget to upvote and accept the post once you verify. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First convert values by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for replace non floats to missing values and then replace them by original values with `00:` for hours, last convert by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with `unit='d'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"time": ["20:00", "0.013391204", "0.013333333",
                            "0.012708333", "0.012280093"]})

s = pd.to_numeric(df['time'], errors='coerce').fillna(df['time'].radd('00:'))
df['new'] = pd.to_timedelta(s, unit='d')
print (df)
          time             new
0        20:00        00:20:00
1  0.013391204 00:19:17.000025
2  0.013333333 00:19:11.999971
3  0.012708333 00:18:17.999971
4  0.012280093 00:17:41.000035
```